# Use next CSV file when all values used

Tags: jmeter

I have 10 CSV files with usernames with 1 million records each. Ideally I want to use an unique value for every thread and when all values from the first CSV file have been used, it should start using the values from the second CSV file, and so on.

Adding multiple CSV Data Set Config elements is no problem and it is easy to add them to a If or While controller. But what can be the trigger to go to the next file?

As an alternative, I use multiple If controller with e.g. `${__eval(${__threadNum})} < 1000` and `${__eval(${__threadNum})} > 1000 and ${__eval(${__threadNum})} < 2000` to make sure the users read from different CSV files, but this is a bit cumbersome when the number of users change often, because you need to change the if conditions accordingly.

Comment: Is there any special reason in not adding all data in single file?

Comment: Excel has a limit of 1 million rows....

Comment: There are other tools also :). Why do you need to open it at first place. For 1M you must not be doing it manually. you might be having a script for generation. write it for 10M and then directly use it.

Comment: I have no influence on the values, nor do I know how to generate them. I just get them from the client to use.

Comment: currently there is no direct facility in Jmeter to provide multiple files to a single CSV data set. Thus I suggest you to merge those files in a single file before use or if you have seperate files then create similar thread groups and provide files to each threadgroup. This will also work

Comment: OK, then the easiest option is to merge the .csv files into 1 file.

Comment: Yes according to me.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider switching to [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function which is capable of fetching data from multiple CSV files. Optionally in conjunction with [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function if you need to switch files based on certain condition

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series for advanced information on aforementioned and more useful JMeter Functions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the problem is that "switch files based on certain condition" is very hard to determine.